# Why is Net::SNMP trying to load the wrong libnetsnmp.so?

Tags: perl, snmp

I created a Perl script and tested it on a couple of servers running [Net::SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SNMP) 5.3.1-19, but now I'm trying to run it on a different server and I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't load '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/default_store.so' for module NetSNMP::default_store: libnetsnmp.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
 at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/SNMP.pm line 16
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/SNMP.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/SNMP.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at /shaw/neteye/perl_scripts/cmtsmonitord.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /shaw/neteye/perl_scripts/cmtsmonitord.pl line 9.
```

Why is the loader complaining about the **libnetsnmp.so.15**? I have **libnetsnmp.so.10** installed in all of the other servers and it works just fine. The symlinks are pointing to the same version (10), not 15. Isn't that required for a later version of **Net::SNMP** (5.4.2.1)?

```
    [user@wb lib]$ sudo /sbin/ldconfig |grep snmp
    /sbin/ldconfig: /usr/lib/libgd.so.2 is not a symbolic link

    [user@wb lib]$ sudo /sbin/ldconfig -p |grep snmp
    libsnmp.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libsnmp.so.10
    libnetsnmptrapd.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libnetsnmptrapd.so.10
    libnetsnmpmibs.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libnetsnmpmibs.so.10
    libnetsnmphelpers.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libnetsnmphelpers.so.10
    libnetsnmpagent.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libnetsnmpagent.so.10
    libnetsnmp.so.10 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libnetsnmp.so.10
```

Why is it trying to use a more recent version of the dynamic library in this server when all of the snmp packages are the same?

I noticed something else. There are 2 sets of **default_store.so** libraries.

```
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/NetSNMP/agent/default_store/default_store.so
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/default_store.so
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/NetSNMP/agent/default_store/default_store.so
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/default_store.so
```

The machines that are working fine only have the **vendor_perl** ones, which is what gets installed with the RPMs. What is the difference between the two (vendor and base)? How do I force perl to use the add on in **vendor_perl**?

Comment: Please add the output of `perl -V` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the

- `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/NetSNMP/agent/default_store/default_store.so`, or
- `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/NetSNMP/default_store/default_store.so`

is linked against a specific version of `libntsnmp.so`, run `ldd` against both of the above files, and see what the output tells you.

Answer (score 0):

If libnetsnmp.so.15 is unknown print:
find / -name libnetsnmp.so.15
cp /.../libnetsnmp.so.15 /usr/lib or in that directory where all libs are allocated
And it's all will be fine...